# Get All Branches MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, recursion, tree

Good day Everyone,

This question might already exist here but just gonna give some try.
Heres my problem im using mysql. 
For example below is my table

ID|PARENT
1  | 0
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 2
6  | 3
7  | 6
8  | 0

Suppose The table is like a tree structure where `PARENT` as parent of `ID` example for 1 there are 2 childs (2 and 3).
And So if i want to get all the connection starting from `1` query will return
1 | 0
2 | 1
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 2
6  | 3
7  | 6

If i want all the connection starting from `[3,2]` the return will be
3 | 1
6 | 3
7 | 6

It will get all the children of children.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Yeah, your using MySQL is kinda a problem in itself :)  But the bigger problem is that SQL sucks at trees.  Google "nested sets" for a better solution to this problem.

Comment: @Edrich I stated above the expected output.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this. I had no choice but to use SQL.